# Develop a simple plugin modular rest reachable service in Java

Tags: java, api, plugins, spring-boot, osgi

I want to develop a service that exposes a rest API to upload plugins and the plugins are locally executable, i.e. other classes from the server use them.

The plugins also:

- The plugin should be a jar file that is submitted through the REST API and once is validated, is then made available through another API method to see the metadata and to execute.
- Are not too complex (they should all contain at least a a class that extends of an abstract class or an interface implementation of an interface, the service) but could have their own dependencies.
- The API allows to validate that the plugin is compliant with the service and that it declares some additional information on an XML or JSON file contained on the JAR.
- Have some metadata that has to be exposed through the API (Version, who made it, is it usable, what data can it be handled) in Json form.
- All implement an algorithm to perform some data crunch so they all have something like an `execute()` method. The result of executing this method is handled to another class, so is not totally important to expose it on the API.
- Must be able to be uploaded and executed by the other server classes in runtime, so no restart is possible

The thing is that I am not sure where to start, since I had already developed some of the basic API on Spring-boot since it had all the things I needed to easily develop a REST API but the more I read about how to dynamically load modules (plugins) the more I see that Spring does not support this ind of thing and I am not sure a class loader or Service loader would work in that context.

I found out about OSGi framework but I honestly do not know it changing the whole technology stack will help me so I want to make sure it is the right answer, and if yes, then find some resources that point me in the right direction, e.g. some tutorial that implements something similar.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org). It includes a model to developing RESTful services: http://enroute.osgi.org/services/osgi.enroute.rest.api.html.

Comment: How well this plays with maven dependencies, I also have other requirements where I need to make some database operations and doing that on JDBC would probably outweight the convenience of having the OSGI framework for supporting the runtime plugin architecture.
Also, how well this standard compares to Apache Karaf?  Since In my understanding I could potentially use Karaf + JAX-RS for the REST endpoints.

Comment: 1) OSGi enRoute allows the addition of all maven dependencies through JPM. 2) Notice that OSGi is not an app server. You bring your own dependencies you do not have to depend on a limited set of standard services available. The enRoute REST is actually a POJO mapping to REST with JSON. This is a lot more OSGi and therefore easier to use than JAX-RS.  (And easy to port to JAX-RS if the need should arise one day.) 3) there is an OSGi spec for a REST API on an OSGi framework.

Comment: That was really helpful @PeterKriens! I will mark this as the answer.
I did however use dynamic class loader library for the specific project I was working on, since I had alreday implemented much of the server on spring. I think that for a mid-novice like myself the documentation of OSGi platforms tends to be less approachable as something like spring-boot.

Answer (score 2):

OSGi sounds like the best match to what you try to do.

You can install everything as a bundle including your main application. Nowadays this is much less work than some years before but still not to be underestimated.

The other option is to start an embedded OSGi framework where you just install your plugins. This is less work but you need to know exactly how it works.

So for both cases I suggest to get help from an external OSGi expert as it speeds up the transition a lot and avoids many wrong paths you will choose as a beginner.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Do you have any recommendations on tutorials, resources for beginners or something you think is particularly useful for this case and cannot be easily found on some google searches?

Comment: You can take a look at my tutorials on Apache Karaf http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials.  They cover how to build OSGi applications but I am not aware of good tutorials for the transition.